# Passing multiple arguments while reading a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read the csv file using pandas, while reading I want to read only few rows and few columns for that I can pass all the arguments like skiprows, nrows inside pd.read_csv. But I don't want to do this way I want to create a separate function and pass this function to pd.read_csv as shown below. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this.

```
import pandas as pd
file = r'C:\Users\Desktop\raw_data\Parameters.csv'

def readheader():
parse_config
{
    'nrows': 200,
    'header': [1,4],
    'skip_blank_lines': True
}
df = pd.read_csv(file, **parse_config)
print(df)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
def someFunction(filepath_or_buffer, skip_blank_lines):
  parse_config = {
      'filepath_or_buffer': filepath_or_buffer,
      'skip_blank_lines': skip_blank_lines
  }
  df = pd.read_csv(**parse_config)

someFunction(filepath_or_buffer='/some_path', skip_blank_lines=False)
```

keys in your parse_config object have to be valid [parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Without modifying the pandas source code, you can't change what parameters are able to be passed to the read_csv method.

Comment: This doesn't work now. I got this error. `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>`

Comment: @atheesh27 without more info (your code, version of pandas, version of python) it's difficult to understand your issue.

Comment: Sorry ! it did work. I upvoted the answer.